# Does anyone know of a Numara Footprints Mylyn Connector for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, jira, mylyn

We're using Numara Footprints for our helpdesk here at my company. Our workflow centers around CFBuilder/Eclipse on a Mac/OS X. We've successfully installed the Jira connector into Eclipse to see which open bugs are assigned to a developer. I'd like to do the same for incoming tickets.

Has anyone written a custom mylyn connector for Numara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could try to use [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Incubator/Generic_SQL_Connector): it is a generic sql connector for Mylyn. It shouldn't be difficult to use it.

otherwise the generc mylyn [Web Connector](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_User_Guide#Generic_Web_Templates_Connector) could help you

saluti